# Tsql convert/cast full string without blank or delimiter to date time

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query log table (system table), it returns:

[image]

After attach the date and time, I need convert:

```
'20160404105625'
```

To dateTime type:

```
2016-04-04 10:56:25.00
```

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the string in the format `"20160404 10:56:25"` to be able to convert it to the desired result:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, run_date + ' ' + LEFT(run_time, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(run_time, 2, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(2, run_time))
FROM your_table
```